# How to remove spring core jar from Grails dependencies?

Tags: spring, grails, dependencies

I am using GGTS 3.2.0 with Grails 2.2.1. How do I remove the spring-core jar from the Grails dependencies in BuildConfig.

Comment: And what is your predicament which makes you feel removing spring core from Grails?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
        inherits("global") {
         excludes 'spring-core'
        }

Comment: You are removing the engine of a car and expect it to run on road. `exlcudes` will exclude all the instances of spring-core. Obviously you will have to end up pushing the car by yourself. :-)